# Using SSR relay

Tags: motor, dc, solid-state-relay

I want to disconnect a negative of a battery connected to a DC motor using SSR relay.can we do it with ac load switching SSR

Comment: most SSRs are AC switching, DC driven. since the input is typically an LED, you can convert the AC into DC to feed it with a FBR+caps. if you need to switch big DC, use a MOSFET

Answer (score 2):

SSRs use one of several types of device to do the actual switchng. One for AC will probably use triacs. These will not switch off if used with DC the current through them has to go to 0 in order for them to switch off.

What you do use to do the switching depends on motor voltage and current and what you are driving it with. In most cases a N-channel Mosfet would be the core component.

Comment: so if i add a mosfet at the output of my ssr it will switch dc right

Comment: or shall i use a mechanical relay for disconnecting my battery's negative,will it suffice

Comment: "*so if i add a mosfet at the output of my ssr it will switch dc right*". Please don't be lazy and capitalise your posts and comments for legibility and credibility. Since a MOSFET is DC controlled you can't control it from a triac based SSR either.

Answer (score 0):

For motors I would use more robust coil relays. Spike current caused when the motor start will quickely burn the Mosfet in the SSR relay. Even if your motor current is rated well below the SSR current. Solenoid relays (coil relays) not only offer much higher current but are much less sensitive to motor spikes above rating.

Comment: A longer answer might be appropriate